Nginx WebDAV: Disable buffering in in /var/lib/nginx/body
I use nginx as a WebDAV server to write large files over the network to the server. Unfortunately nginx stores all files in /var/lib/nginx/body and only writes them to the final destination once the entire file is transferred. I have already tried the following in the server block:
# do not store in /var/lib/nginx/body
client_max_body_size 0;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_request_buffering off;

Within the server directive without any success. Nginx 1.22.1 (Debian Bookworm) still buffers the files in /var/lib/nginx/body before writing them to disk. How can I completely disable this buffering?
